# Batch - Execute a command IF program output critera is met

Tags: batch-file

Sorry about the lousy title, I don't really know how to fit my question into a few words.

This may probably seem trivial to you guys, but I'm trying to automate a task that goes something like this:

- Check if a certain executable exists
- If it exists, run the executable, which has two possible outcomes:

  - Update found.
  - Update not found.
- If outcome A, run a certain command. If outcome B, run another command.

The executable gives an output in the command line window, but I'm stranded on how to make the IF command read the output and use it.

English isn't my first language and my vocabulary regarding this is rather limited, so just let me know if something isn't clear.

Comment: what operating system is this for?  What have you tried so far?  Have you gotten any error messages?

Comment: Sorry about that. This is supposed to run on Windows 7 and eventually Windows 8. I've been trying to read up on the FOR command, but I can't seem to wrap my head around it. This is my first time making a "complex" script like this.

Comment: have you tried reviewing the `Powershell` as a possible alternative to `cmd`?  Also, it looks like the `for` command is meant to be used thusly: `for %%files in (myfile.txt myotherfile.txt more.txt) DO copy %%files C:\myfolder`
http://www.computerhope.com/forhlp.htm
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490890.aspx

Comment: What is the text of the 2 possible outcomes? update your post with them.

Comment: @MattWilliamson Post has been updated.

Comment: Please post the code you have so far and identify the problem more specifically, rather than just describing what you want to do. Explain how the results differ from the desired results, and include any error messages you receive. Please read the [About](http://stackoverflow.com/about) page and [this advice on asking good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: BTW, I agree with @AlexejMagura that unless there's a specific reason to use batch (such as that it's being deployed as a login or startup script for different versions of Windows, you're better off using PowerShell, for both small and large tasks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if exist path\filename.ext anycommand` checks, if a file exists and if yes, executes anycommand

`anycommand >temp.txt` writes the output of a command to a textfile.

`set /p variable=<temp.txt` writes the content of the textfile to a variable (well, at least the first line)

`if "%variable%"=="Update not found" othercommand` runs othercommand, if %variable% is equal to "Update not found"

Answer (score 0):

Something along these lines might be what you're looking for: (This is an example, not the exact program)

```
set file_path=C:\Users\Atyai\Desktop\ExampleFile.bat
if exist %file_path% echo Update Found. && ::Then put your command right here
if not exist %file_path% echo Update Not Found. && ::Put your other command here
```

What this does, is when the file exists, it echoes "Update found" then I left some room for your second command. In the case that the file does not exist, it echoes "Update Not Found."
The file path I gave you (first line) needs to be replaced with your own.

This might provide some help:
http://ss64.com/nt/if.html